# Adding Markers To A New Google Map Initialized After An AJAX Call with Gmaps4rails 1.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am trying to add markers to a google map created after an ajax call.  I have added the js files directly to my page as noted in other SO posts. My code after the ajax request is as follows

```
markers = [{lat: '43.1777', lng: '-87.9944'}];
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle;
Gmaps.map.markers = markers
Gmaps.map.createServiceMarkersFromMarkers()
Gmaps.map.initialize()
Gmaps.loadMaps()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you have a map on your page and you want to update it.

In this case, simply use:

```
 Gmaps.map.addMarkers(your_markers_json_array);     //this is a JS function
```

[It's described here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies).

Comment: adding the `markers` given above returns `TypeError: Cannot call method 'fitBounds' of null`

Comment: Is the array you provide null?

Comment: The array is not null.  I am providing the array `markers` as shown above. `Gmaps.map.addMarkers(markers);`

Comment: any luck with this or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Yes please fill a bug report with more details

Comment: I figured it out, the map needs to be initialized before markers can b e added to it.